# Fundamental form of an almost complex manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, almost-complex

Let $(M^{2m},h,J)$ be an almost Hermitian manifold with fundamental form $\Omega$.

I want a local expression for this $\Omega (X,Y)=h(JX,Y)$ in this almost-complex manifold, but during my computations I struggle with the almost complex structure $J$. The only thing I know is that $J^2=-Id$.

So my questions so far are:

1. What does the (1,1)-tensor $J$ do with an arbitrary vector field X (local/global)?
2. Would it be better to do the computations in a local orthonormal frame?
3. Does a Riemannian metric in a local orthonormal frame behave like the standard inner product?

Comment: $J$ is the action of $i$ on the tangent space at every point.

Comment: so I have to complexify the tangent bundle first? In a local chart $(U,\phi )$ with $\phi =(x_1,\dots,x_{2m})$ I can write the metric tensor as $h=\sum_{k,l=1}^{2m}{h_{kl}\cdot dx_k\otimes dx_l}$. As J is the action of $i$, this gives as $\Omega =ih$? How is $\Omega$ then skew-symmetric?

Comment: Also according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_manifold#Riemannian_metric_and_associated_form), your definition of the fundamental form is wrong, unless you wanted a [skew-Hermitian form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form#Skew-Hermitian_form). To see that $\Omega$ is skew-Hermitian, observe that $h(JX,Y) = ih(X,Y) = i\overline{h(Y,X)} = \overline{-ih(Y,X)} = -\overline{h(JY,X)}$.

Comment: I think part of what confuses me about this question is that you're asking for a local expression for $\Omega(X,Y)=h(JX,Y)$, but that expression is already valid globally, locally, or even pointwise. Thus I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for in an answer.

Comment: Also as for question 3, a Riemannian metric behaves like the standard inner product in any frame, but in an orthonormal frame, its matrix is the identity matrix, which is the same matrix as that of the dot product on $\Bbb{R}^n$ with respect to the standard basis.

Comment: It makes sense that $h$ is skew-Hermitian and the whole thing is $C$-valued, thanks. I think what I am looking for is a representation as linear combination of wedge products but not in a Hermitian manifold with holomorphic atlas but in an almost Hermitian manifold. I thought of these almost complex manifolds to be real and searched for a concrete representation of $J$ as real endomorphism of the tangent bundle.

Comment: My goal I think is first compute the linear/wedge combination for $\Omega$ of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ (basis vector in tangent space) and duals and the image under $J$, then take a local orthonormal frame and compute $\Omega$ in that frame. I don't understand the step from combination of tensor products of $ih$ to combination of wedges. I hope this clears it up :D

Comment: My point was that $\Omega$, as you've defined it, isn't a differential form. It's not skew-symmetric, it's skew-Hermitian. You can't write it as a wedge product. There is such a thing as the fundamental form, but it's basically the real part of $\Omega$ (which is of course alternating, since complex conjugation doesn't affect the real part).

Comment: Also it should be possible to write $J$ as a direct sum of copies of $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ in an appropriate local frame.

Comment: I think it should be possible then to further adjust your frame to get $h$ in the form of the standard Hermitian product, but I'd have to write that out.

Comment: Ah. The process is fairly clear actually. Begin by choosing a complex frame $v_1,\ldots,v_m$, such that $h$ is the standard Hermitian product. This is possible by Gram-Schmidt, starting with an arbitrary frame. Then to get $J$ in the desired form, select the real basis $v_1,Jv_1,v_2,Jv_2,\ldots,v_m,Jv_m$.

Comment: The last thing I should add is that while almost Hermitian manifolds are real manifolds, the complex numbers and the linear algebra of complex vector spaces are still crucial to understanding them.

Comment: My calculations are still wrong/uncomplete. But I have the feeling I'm getting closer to my problem: We have an almost Hermitian manifold like stated above. Moroianu introduces a (real) algebraic operator on differential forms via $L:\Lambda ^k M\rightarrow\Lambda^{k+2}, L(\omega)=\Omega\wedge\omega =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{2m}{e_i\wedge Je_i\wedge\omega}$. From this I conclude $\Omega =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{2m}{e_i\wedge Je_i}$. This is my goal and I bet I can prove this without complexifying. So $J$ is a real endomorphism with $J^2=-id$ and $\{e_1,\dots ,e_{2m}$  local orthonormal real frame

Comment: $h$ is Riemannian metric and i.p. symmetric, so I can write $h=\sum_{i,j=1}^{2m}{e_i\otimes e_j+e_j\otimes e_i}$. Using our global formula for $\Omega$ yields then $\Omega = -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^{2m}{Je_i\otimes e_j+Je_j\otimes e_i}$, clearly too far away from goal. Extending the summands of $h$ by additional $Je_i\otimes Je_j+Je_j\otimes Je_i$ yields $\Omega = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^{2m}{e_i\wedge Je_j+e_j\wedge Je_i}$ which is in my opinion much better but still not what I want. Although your comments helped me very much understanding what I dont understand, I dont get to the (real)end.

Comment: I sort of assume you mean that the $e_i$ are a local orthonormal coframe, but ok. Wait $h$ is the Riemannian metric? So it's the real part of the Hermitian metric. That clarifies things a lot. Your expression for $h$ is definitely wrong, since it comes out to something crazy, like the matrix which is all 2s or something. Also there shouldn't be a global formula for $\Omega$, just a local one, limited to the region of validity of our coframe.

Answer (score 0):

Your comments have now led me to a proper understanding of the question, and I can now write an answer.

We have the following set up. $M$ is a $2m$-manifold, with almost complex structure $J$ and a Riemannian metric $h$ that preserves the almost complex structure. I.e., so that $h(Ju,Jv)=h(u,v)$ for all tangent vectors $u$ and $v$ at every point.

You then define the fundamental form $\Omega(X,Y) = h(JX,Y)$, which is skew symmetric, since $$\Omega(Y,X) = h(JY,X) = h(X,JY) = h(JX,J^2Y) = h(JX,-Y) = -\Omega(X,Y).$$

I'll note at this point that your choice of letters is slightly misleading. I would expect $g$ for the Riemannian metric, and wikipedia leads me to expect $\omega$ for the fundamental form. However, now that the meanings have been clarified, it doesn't really matter what letters you picked.

Let $e_i$ be a local orthonormal frame. It's kind of poor notation to regard the vectors $e_i$ as covectors, even though they are canonically identified with such via $h$. Thus let $\theta_i$ be the dual basis, $\theta_i(x) = h(e_i,x)$. Observe that $h(Je_i,-) = -h(e_i,J-)$, so the dual of $Je_i$ is $-\theta_i J$.

Now you want to show that 
$$\Omega = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_i \theta_i \wedge \theta_i J.$$

First, since $e_i$ are orthonormal, observe that the entries of the matrix for $J$ with respect to the $e_i$ are $J_{ij} = h(e_i,Je_j)$. Also since $h(Jx,Jy)=h(x,y)$, $J$ is orthonormal, so $J^T = J^{-1}$.

To do so, observe that $Je_i$ is also an orthonormal frame, so it suffices to show that both sides agree for all pairs $(e_i,Je_j)$ that we evaluate them at.
Evaluating $\Omega$ first, we get $$\Omega(e_i,Je_j) = h(Je_i,Je_j) = \delta_{ij}.$$
Now evaluating the right hand side, we have
$$-\frac{1}{2} \sum_k \theta_k(e_i)\theta_k(J^2e_j) - \theta_k(Je_j)\theta_k(Je_i)$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2} \sum_k -\delta_{ik}\delta_{jk} - h(e_k,Je_j)h(e_k,Je_i)$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2}\sum_k \delta_{ik}\delta_{jk} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_k J_{kj}J_{ki}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_k J^T_{ik}J_{kj}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij} + \frac{1}{2} \delta_{ij} = \delta_{ij},$$
as desired.